# copy and paste next without for vba error

Tags: vba, excel

I have a sheet of data and in my data range column O has two values, new or previously pending which is based on another column with formulas. I m hoping to loop through each cell in column O and see which cells are new and paste it as values only. Right now I am getting `next without for` error.

Here is the part of my vba codes that failed.

```
'Values
With ActiveSheet.Range("O:O")
    Dim x As Long
    For x = 100 To 2 Step -1
         If Cells(x, 15).Value = "New" Then
         Cells(x, 15).Copy
         Cells(x, 15).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Next x
 End With
```

Comment: You're missing an `End If`

Comment: What's the purpose of your `With` statement here? `Cells()` are unqualified and referring to the `ActiveSheet` already.

Comment: This compile-time error is happening because your `If` block isn't closed, so since there is no `For` statement within the `If` block, the compiler is encountering a `Next` statement which is out of place, hence: Next without For.

Comment: Thank you, it resolved my issue with the error.

Comment: Thank you I removed the with statement as well.

Comment: Thank you Mathieu, I will certain try the Rubberduck indenter going forward.

Comment: All this is doing is looking for cells that say "New" and pasting them onto themselves? I can't imagine why.

Comment: @ashleedawg - because "New" is a calculated value that updates every time the sheet is recalculated. OP wants to calculate which cells are "New", then make that (semi-)permanent by replacing the formula with a fixed value. Presumably, sometime later, something else will process the "New" cells/rows/whatever and change "New" to "somethingelse".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to start from the bottom to the top and you can count the rows so you don't loop to long.

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim Rng As Range, c As Range
    Set Rng = Range("O2:O" & Cells(Rows.Count, "O").End(xlUp).Row)
    For Each c In Rng.Cells
        If c = "New" Then c.Value = c.Value
    Next c
End Sub
```